# Waiting for uploadifyUpload() to complete before processing rest of script

Tags: jquery, uploadify, validation

I'm using uploadifyUpload() from within a script like this:

```
$("#artist_form").validator({
    offset: [0, 100],
    position: 'center left',
    messageClass: 'arterror'
}).submit(function(e) {
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {

        $('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload();

        var form = $(this);
        var serdata = form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendartist.php",
            data: serdata,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                log('inside ajax artist', this, arguments);
                if (html=="0") {
                    alert("An error occurred");
                } else {
                    alert("Sent ok");
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                log('inside ajax artist', this, arguments);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

As you can see, before the upload even has a chance to complete the form has been sent. This isn't good cus I need to do something with the uploaded files in 'sendartist.php' thats doing the processing.

Is there a way to add some sort of callback to uploadifyUpload() so that the script only continues if it's complete?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your Ajax call within Uploadify setup function using its onAllComplete event.
Have a look at documentation: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/onallcomplete/

Comment: Ah I was looking at it a bit backwards. Thanks fella!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set in settings:

```
simUploadLimit: 999
```