# using uploadify in ajax

Tags: jquery, uploadify

Hi I am uploading image with `uploadify`. I am calling the

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify('upload');
```

In ajax success so that it will upload image to my local folder. See below code:

```
     ajax.Post("AddEvent.aspx/AddEvent", JSON.stringify({ ObjEnt: args }), false).success(function (data) {


                 $('#file_upload').uploadify('upload');

            --->

                    if (data.d[0] > 0) {

                        args["EventId"] = data.d[0];

                        if (!args.Status) {

                            self.EventsList.unshift(args);
                            self.EventsList.splice(-1, 1);
                            logger.success(data.d[1]);
```

Here I want to use the response of my `uploadify` like if the upload is success then the next step i mentioned with arrow should execute..

```
                  var file = $('#file_upload').uploadify('upload');
                  if(file=='true')
                   {
                        //do whatever  

                   }
```

and what I found in doc.s that response of `uploadify` can get from  `onUploadSuccess`..
Similar question found on SE but no more answer i found there.
  [Waiting for uploadifyUpload() to complete before processing rest of script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198142/waiting-for-uploadifyupload-to-complete-before-processing-rest-of-script)

Answer (score 1):

Uploadify is all about multiple files, but your question is not very clear.

If you want something to happen after *each file is uploaded successfully* use `onUploadSuccess`:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify('upload', {
    onUploadSuccess : function(file, data, response) {
           // YOUR CODE HERE
    }
});
```

If you want something to run after *all uploads are completed successfully*, use a function assigned to `onQueueComplete` in the options parameter (second parameter to uploadify):

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify('upload', {
    onQueueComplete : function(queueData) {
           if (queueData.uploadsErrored == 0){
               // YOUR CODE HERE
           }
    }
});
```

Note in JavaScript quotes are only required on anonymous object property names (like `'onUploadSuccess'`) that contain invalid characters (like `-`). In the examples shown you do not need them.

Comment: he tring to return data from ashx handler

Comment: @sakir: Say what? :) Please clarify what you mean as the existing code makes little sense at the moment :)

Comment: : ) same question with the same user is here. take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107051/using-uploadify-with-ashx-handler/24107663#24107663