# Using uploadify with ashx handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Hi friends i have a form in which there are some text boxes, drop downs and as well as image . I am using knock out js to save the form details. And i am using uploadify plugin to upload my image to a local folder .I have implemented all this things but when it comes to saving the values till now i used a aspx code behind . For uploading purpose we had to choose ashx. So it will be like two server side postings going to happen!!

So i would like to save my data in ashx page rather than aspx.

But i am confused where exactly to start my upload..please some one help me with this!!!

i am saving my values in a save button event like below!!

```
     self.AddEvent = function (args) {          

       // Here--> $('#file_upload').uploadify('upload');

                    ajax.Post("../Scripts/uploadify/UploadHandler.ashx", JSON.stringify({ objEnt: args }), false).success(function (data) {   

                    if (data.d[0] > 0) {
        // or Here-->            $('#file_upload').uploadify('upload');
                    alert('success');
                  }
```

and my fileupload setting s are:

```
   $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'swf': '../Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader': '../Scripts/uploadify/UploadHandler.ashx',
                'method': 'post',
                'formData': { 'someKey': Filename },
                'buttonText': 'Browse',
                'auto': false,
                'folder': 'upload',

                'fileTypeExts': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
                'onSelect': function (file) {
                    var ext = file.name.split('.').pop();
                    $("#filename").val(Filename + '.' + ext);
                },
                'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {

                    if (response == true) {

                       $("#eventGrid").jqxGrid('updatebounddata');



                    }

                }

            });
```

It is not possible to call self.AddEvent in 'onUploadsuccess' in my situation...!!!
Please suggest me some best way to store my data and image at same time in ashx handler.

ashx:

```
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    var data = context.Request;
    var sr = new StreamReader(data.InputStream);
    var stream = sr.ReadToEnd();
    var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var asd = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(stream);
    string Newname = context.Request.Form["someKey"];
    BAL Bl = new BAL();

    string[] args = new string[2];
   //AddEvent method will add my data into database add return response "Success"//
    args = AddEvent(asd.objEnt);

        HttpPostedFile PostedFile = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];

            string ext = Path.GetExtension(PostedFile.FileName);
            string savepath = "";
            string temppath = "";
            temppath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"];
            savepath = context.Server.MapPath(temppath);
            string fileName = Newname + ext;
            if (!Directory.Exists(savepath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(savepath);

            PostedFile.SaveAs(savepath + @"\" + fileName);

            context.Response.Write(temppath + "/" + fileName);
           // context.Response.Write(args);

            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;

        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use it like this,first load all images later  if success  happens ,inside the success in uplodify ,make a anaother ajax call which has save the data

Comment: But tell me one thing how can i get the returned value of ashx handler's response?? I know that context.response.write(args) will write in console. But how can i get the returned value in ajax success??

Comment: I appreciate ur help!! any example links would be much helpful!!

Comment: u mean in 'onUploadSuccess' i have to make a ashx handler request?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").uploadify({
            'uploader': 'Upload.ashx',
            'swf': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script': 'Upload.ashx',
            'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
            'folder': '../Upload',
            'multi': true,
            'buttonText': 'select picture',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.jpeg',
            'auto': false,
            'onUploadStart': function () {


            }
        });


$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'WebServiceAdmin.asmx/SaveData',
            data: "{'p':'" + datam+ "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (d) { $('#FileUpload1').uploadify('upload', '*');  },
            error: function () {  }
        });
```

Comment: with this ashx will be called two times right..? one at the time of posting and second at the time of uploading image..

Comment: on the success function of Ajax how could i get the response of ashx which is 'd' in your case..?? see args in my code!!! based on the response i have to make other things

Comment: U can check uplodify document.shoul be another evet which triger all update finished

Comment: Well ok.maybe u csn use cooki .creatte a cpokie inside ashx,later get it from client side,